# Máscara com jQuery ou HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mask

a Máscara que eu preciso é essa:

0000000-00.0000.0.00.0000

Conforme eu for digitando no input vai sendo preenchida da direito para a esquerda preservando os zeros da direita até que alcance o limite de caracteres desta cadeia.

Exemplos:

0000000-00.0000.0.00.0000

0000000-00.0000.0.00.0001

0000000-00.0000.0.00.0012

0000000-00.0000.0.00.0123

0000000-00.0000.0.00.1234

0000000-00.0000.0.01.2345

0000000-00.0000.0.12.3456

0000000-00.0000.1.23.4567

0000000-00.0001.2.34.5678

0000000-00.0012.3.45.6789

0000000-00.0123.4.56.7891

0000000-00.1234.5.67.8912

0000000-01.2345.6.78.9123

0000000-12.3456.7.89.1234

0000001-23.4567.8.91.2345

....

Em PHP poderia se utilizar o str_pad

Answer (score 0):

Aqui vai a idéia de uma possível solução, você cria uma função que será disparada no elemento text do seu HTML, a cada digitação de um caracter. O que ela deve fazer:

- Validar se o elemento é um número de 0 a 9.
- Se foi validado, verificar se excedeu a quantidade de elementos 20 números pelo que eu pude ver.
- se chegou no ultimo elemento ou seja se após a digitação o lenght da string é 20
  se for, chame uma outra função para realizar a formatação do campo, e execute o método blur() para sair do campo automaticamente.
- Essa função de formatação deve pegar numero com 20 posições e guardar em uma variável depois com o método slice retire os primeiros 7 caracteres e concatene com "-", guarde em uma variável, tipo str_final, e continue retirando elementos da string original e concatenando na str_final agora com os pontos.
  var str_original = "00000000333444455566"; 
  var str_final = str_final + str_original.slice(0,7) + "-";
  str_final = str_final + ...;

Se eu pensar em algo melhor eu te passo...mas por enquanto espero ter ajudado!